# scss create array 1 to 100 without writing it litteraly

Tags: sass, scss-mixins

So I have this mixin:

```
@mixin generateSpacings($prefix, $property) {
    $sizes: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32];
...
```

and obviously writing this array like that is ugly and not really maintainable, how could I write it programatically ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [Codepen](https://codepen.io/SimplyCius/pen/abNKwEP)

I'd go for a solution where I'd generate the array via a `@for` loop and then append it to a list.

```
$start: 1;
$end: 100;

$array: "";

// array[1] = "", so $start + 1 to later set `""` to $start
@for $i from $start + 1 through $end {
  $array: append($array, $i, comma);

  //set `""` to $start
  $array: set-nth($array, 1, $start);
}
```